# How to keep the bottom control bar being hid always, even after dialog shows up and closes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-alertdialog

What I implemented is like this.

I set it in the activity.

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Status bar should not be hid, but just control bar.

And then when I open a dialog and dismiss it I call this method below:

```
    private fun setDefaultUi(dialog: Dialog?) {
        var decorView: View? = null
        if (dialog == null) {
            decorView = this.window.decorView
        } else {
            decorView = dialog!!.window.decorView
        }
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY // hide status bar and nav bar after a short delay, or if the user interacts with the middle of the screen
                )
    }
```

something Like this:

```
    private fun showMyDialog() {
        noticeUrlDialog = Dialog(this)
        noticeUrlDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_my)

        val btnClose = myDialog!!.btn_close

        btnX.setOnClickListener {
            myDialog!!.dismiss()
            setDefaultUi(null)
        }
        myDialog!!.show()
        setDefaultUi(myDialog)
    }
```

In this way, I can hide the bottom control bar which comes up after a dialog pops up and closes.

But I don't think it is a proper way. I need to call the method many times And also, the control bar is shown for a second before `setDefaultUi()`. So, I'd like to know if there's better way?

Comment: use listener(OnCancelListener) for dialog. On cancel, hide navigationbar.

Answer (score 1):

I only managed to achieve it on all APIs and devices using `SystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` when listening ui changes and applying flags again. Here is example code in Kotlin:

```
fun hideStatusBar() {
        DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(activity)
        activity?.window?.decorView?.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
            if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
                DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(activity)
            }
        }
    }
```

and  `DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(activity)` :

```
object DisplayUtil {
 fun hideStatusBar(activity: Activity?) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
            } else {
                activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
            }
        }
}
```

Also don't forget to remove listener when it is not needed.

Comment: I want to show status bar(transparent) and hide the control bar.

Comment: this code hides status bar and control bar. Change UI flags to only hide control bar and you will have what you want.

Comment: Where can I get `DisplayUtil`?

Comment: please read whole answer or just use your code that hides control bar instead DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(activity)

Comment: No, I don't have `DisplayUtil` class. Do I have to use some extra library? What is it?

Comment: Use the above answer and let me know if it works fine.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear what is DisplayUtil

Comment: It works better and cleaner but not perfectly. When a dialog pops up, the control bar shows up for a second(while dialog is shown). If there's better solution, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain immersive mode, you need to set `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` to the dialog's layout params before you show it. However this will also prevent the user from interacting with the dialog so you need to clear this flag after you call `show()`.

```
private fun showMyDialog() {
        noticeUrlDialog = Dialog(this)
        noticeUrlDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_my)

        val btnClose = myDialog!!.btn_close

        btnX.setOnClickListener {
            myDialog!!.dismiss()
            setDefaultUi(null)
        }

        myDialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
        myDialog!!.show()
        myDialog!!.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

        setDefaultUi(myDialog)
    }
```